# Simple product images on product page, search/category and basket pages

Tags: extensions, swatches

I know people have asked about being able to using a simple product's image on configurable products before but none of the solutions seem to cover everything we're looking for. What we want is to:

- Show the selected simple product's image when chosen from the dropdown on the product page (not swatches)
- Only show images for colours which are in stock for the additional images/thumbnails
- Show the simple product's image in the basket when added
- Only show the colour selected from the layered navigation as the product image on the category page

As I say, I've read many other posts which have been similar but don't cover everything. Does there exist an extension which would achieve all this? One that would cover most of it and the rest could be configured separately?

We're running Magento 1.7.0.0

Any help would be appreciated